# How to Change Swiper Navegation Default Colors

Tags: css, swiper.js

I need the pagination and arrows to be green.
How can I override the default blue colour in these elements?

This is what I'm working with:

CSS

```
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

swiper-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML

```css
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    color: #ccc !important;
    }
```

```html
  <swiper-container class="mySwiper" pagination="true" pagination-clickable="true" navigation="true" space-between="30"
    loop="true">
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swiper uses CSS Variables to set colours.

So all you need to do is declare --swiper-navigation-color and --swiper-pagination-color in the :root of your CSS

```
:root {
  --swiper-navigation-color: red;
  --swiper-pagination-color: red;
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the **:after** pseudo-element of the buttons like this:

```
.swiper-button-prev:after,
.swiper-button-next:after {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style="--swiper-navigation-color:var(--your-navigation-color, #424141);"
```

Inside style attribute into the `swiper-container` tag.